# Filtering Foursquare Venue Results

Tags: api, location, foursquare

I am currently evaluating several different APIs in order to get venue information. A key component of any provider is the ability to not just return **all** venues nearby but tailor the list based on previously entered user preferences.

Foursquare does not allow 'munging' their venue data with other data, like Google's places to create an aggregated service. **But can I take Foursquare's venues for a given area, apply some filtering based on user preferences and recommendation engine techniques, and present a modified, personalized version of their information? Do they frown on only using their venue info as a jumping off point, even if attribution on the final results is given?**

This customization would be above and beyond using retailer categories, something that can be included in the facebook request. Asking because other services require results presented exactly as returned from the API, including ads.

Answer (score 0):

First, check out the policies at https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community

> We welcome you to use foursquare as your location database. You can associate additional content with our venue data in your system, but you may not combine our database with another database or export it on your own.

I think that they even encourage you to manipulate the data and create creative solutions with it, as long as you do not break their ground rule of not merging it with another database (see the full text at the link).

The API even lets you filter the results according to your needs with the categoryId and intent parameters. For example in our app, we filter out places that have less than 2 unique people checked in, because we assume its faked places.. we do other filtering on the result set as well, but we display **only** data from from foursquare venues database, and we attribute.

Comment: Yes, I've reviewed their policy doc, and that is part of the problem; it seems to raise more questions than it answers.

I can understand them not wanting their location information merged with something like Google Places - both services do the same thing. But what if I took their results for venues, limited them to retail establishments, and then combined it with a service like Milo to display products at those places? As long as I'm giving attribution does this fall under ***"creative solutions"*** or is it ***"combining their database"***?

Comment: I would say it sounds cool, because you are not combining their database with another venue/places provider, you are extending the data they provide, for example, the same way an instagram photo has a foursquare location attached to it if available.. this is of course, my interpretation for what you said, if I were you I would mail them at api@foursqaure.com to make sure they think the same.

Comment: suppose i make a search for nightclubs but i want to filter through the result to show only a some of them. Is it possible to do that without saving those places in my own database?